# when i run this command php bin/console make:reset-password i get a problem

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony

when i run this command php bin/console make:reset-password i get a problem from In AbstractManagerRegistry.php line 158:Doctrine ORM Manager named "" does not exist.

```
php bin/console make:reset-password
```

from In AbstractManagerRegistry.php line 158:Doctrine ORM Manager named "" does not exist.
i used mongodb and symfony 5

Comment: the make:reset-password command assumes one uses doctrine-orm (with a relational database) and not doctrine-odm (mongodb and the like). If you are a beginner, I would suggest you start with a relational database. Otherwise you just can't use most of the maker-bundle, afaik.

Comment: hi, what is the syntax for odm?

Comment: well, the maker-bundle is just a helper to generate among others pages like password reset. as far as i know, it doesn't exist for odm, sorry. But I bet there are some tutorials for building stuff like it, where you have to replace orm stuff with odm stuff.